# Annotated heatmap with multiple color schemes from two different columns of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
Percent category  MolA  MolB
  20      1     02K@sc  81G@bs
  15      0     04F@sc  79U@bs
  16      2     04F@sc  79U@sg
  18      1     04F@sc  80A@bs
  4       0     04F@sc  80A@ph
```

I want to plot the MolA column against MolB according to percent value. For coloring each category should be in different color for example 0 -->Blue, 1 --> Red, 2-->Green and then the hue/shades of these color will be according to percentage.

I tried using the `sns.colorpalette("YlGnBu", 30)` but this is not exactly what I want and this seems to be not very clear for distinguishing between two different categories.

Is it possible to plot the dataframe in such way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to leverage the behavior of heatmap automatically excluding null values from the map by iterating over each category, nulling out `Percent` not in that category and making a heatmap for the resulting pivot table.  If you loop that you may be able to get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Percent': [20, 15, 16, 18, 4],
 'category': [1, 0, 2, 1, 0],
 'MolA': ['02K@sc', '04F@sc', '04F@sc', '04F@sc', '04F@sc'],
 'MolB': ['81G@bs', '79U@bs', '79U@sg', '80A@bs', '80A@ph']})


palettes = ['Blues','Greens','Oranges']

for c, p in zip(df.category.unique(), palettes):
    t = df.copy()
    t['Percent'] = np.where(t['category'].ne(c), np.nan, df['Percent'])
    sns.heatmap(t.pivot('MolA','MolB','Percent'), cbar=False, cmap=p, annot=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This coloring scheme does not work when there's a category missing.
For example:
`
df = pd.DataFrame({'Percent': [20, 15, 16, 18, 4],
 'category': [2, 0, 2,0, 0],
 'MolA': ['02K@sc', '04F@sc', '04F@sc', '04F@sc', '04F@sc'],
 'MolB': ['81G@bs', '79U@bs', '79U@sg', '80A@bs', '80A@ph']})
`
And we have ['Blues','Greens','Oranges'] for 0, 1 and 2 respectively.
But it misses the Green for 1 and assigns Green to 2 as category 1 is missing.

We need to pass the category list in zip() to solve this like :
`
category_list = [0,1,2]
for c, p in zip(category_list, palettes):
`

Comment: If you want to keep the colors static, perhaps use a dictionary like `d={0:'Blues',1:'Greens}` etc and in your plot function `cmap=d['c']` where c is the unique categories.

Comment: And is it possible to add the shades only from the 50-100% range? For example, the color for blue 10% and green 10% (or any other shades from the lower range) is not very distinguishable, so it would be nice to start the color shade range from a slightly dark palette.